# Json data Copy and replace automate

Tags: json, bash, scripting, notepad++

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I have a json file with close to 10000 elements, out of which I need to make a copy of 2000 elements based on a condition and replace an attribute when doing so..

Ex.
Input : jsonData.json
//Other elements

```
  {
  "_id" :ObjectId("123"),
  "_arryAtt" : {

  "attr1":"dummy",
  "attr2":"123"
  }
  }
```

//Other elements

Output : jsonData.json

//Other elements

```
 {
 "_id" :ObjectId("123"), 
 "_arryAtt" : {

  "attr1":"dummy",
  "attr2":"123"
  }
  }


 {

 "_arryAtt" : {

  "attr1":"dummy",
  "attr2":"567"
  }
  }
```

//Other elements

Id is missing in the copied object..

I am familiar with java
How can I achieve this if I don't' want to write a custom parser... 
What kind of scripting can I use to automate this, as running this manually to copy 2000 elements and change one attribute is difficult..

Comment: You should add an real example what you want achieve. So, some "short" but **real** example of input and the wanted output. The your input isn't a valid JSON, not only because of the invalid `ObjectId("123")`, but also here is a missing comma after `"attr1"="dummy"`. The more precise question could lead to some helpful answers.

Comment: Thanks jm66 for responding back, the real example is I have a json dump of configurations for a site across environments, and when I am adding a new env, I need to copy configs in the same file of rev1 and change one attribute to say "rev2". I wish I had these in separate files per env, but it is all in big file and can import only that to our mongo instance

Comment: Probably it can be done very easily with `perl`. But without an real example, i can't write for you the example script. E.g. on what criteria you need select the 2000 from 10k, what attr you need change, how to fix the invalid JSON (like the above `ObjectId("123")`) and so on.. Many opened questions to provide an real answer. If perl is OK for you - take a look to: https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON

Comment: Perl would be a good solution, but you might want to look into the `jq` utility.  See http://stedolan.github.io/jq/